# Sync code changes in electron app while developing

Tags: javascript, electron, nodemon, livereload

Are there any tools to live reload electron app when code is changed similar to browser-sync for web?

Whenever we change code for electron app, I am terminating existing running process and relaunching with 
*electron .*
Are they any tools to reload electron app automatically when code is changed.

Comment: If you are using React you can have a look at: https://github.com/geowarin/electron-hot-loader

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The best tool (and easiest) I've found is [electron-reload](https://github.com/yan-foto/electron-reload):

```
// main.js
const electron = require('electron');
const { app, BrowserWindow } = electron;
const path = require('path');

// the first argument can be: a file, directory or glob pattern
require('electron-reload')(__dirname + '/app/index.html', {
  electron: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules', '.bin', 'electron')
});

let mainWindow;

app.on('ready', () => {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    // ...
  });
  mainWindow.setMenu(null);

  mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/app/index.html`);
  process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' && mainWindow.openDevTools();
});
```

Answer (score 52):

In this case, you should take a look at development tools for [NodeJS process management](https://github.com/sindresorhus/awesome-nodejs#process-management). My personal favorite is [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon) because you can either use config file or pass something like this:

```
nodemon --watch . --exec "electron ."
```

And it will work just fine. But again, it's my opinion, pick the right for you from the list.

Comment: I was using create-react-app for the frontend (renderer side) of things and most electron reload solutions were about reloading frontend and the backend (main process).

This was perfect, just added a new script in package json, `"electron:watch": "nodemon --watch * --exec 'electron .'"`.

Comment: Just one note here, in the `package.json` the exact line would be `"dev": "nodemon --watch . --exec 'electron . --debug'",` - with watching {dot} location and switched single-double-quotes.

Comment: improving boldnik's answer it should be `"dev": "nodemon --watch . --exec \"electron . --debug\""`

Comment: This works! With market solution - there were build issues with having sqlite3 in my package.json

Comment: I added this command to package.json
"dev": "nodemon --watch . --exec \"webpack && electron . --debug\""
to my Electron(Angular 5 + TypeScript) project electron application is started  but it is not restarting the electron app or updating the changes on UI.

Anyon e can help me on this!

Comment: By default, it checks for JS, MJS, and JSON. If you want nodemon to watch other file types, such as HTML and CSS, you can run: `nodemon --watch . --exec "electron . --debug" -e js,json,html,css`

Comment: A problem I have is that in each restart VS Code looses focus as the electron app gains it. As a consequence in practice it is not usable with auto save on.

Comment: Update 2023
`--debug` is invalid. Please use `--inspect` instead

Answer (score 5):

If you directly use the command "**electron .**",

```
"nodemon": "nodemon --exec electron ."
```

then it will give you an **error**

```
'electron' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
 operable program or batch file.
```

So Use it **Indirectly**,

```
"start": "electron .",
"start:nodemon": "nodemon --watch main.js --exec npm start",
```

and restart your app with

```
npm run start:nodemon
```

Answer (score 3):

A little late answer but I hope it helps everyone.
There is an `npm` module called Electromon.

```
npm i -g electromon [install]
```

Usage would be electron .\main.js
[change name of main.js to your files like app.js or something. ]

Answer (score 0):

I am using swc to compile the typescript files into js files so I fixed the reload with this commands

```
"start": "electron .",
"build": "swc build ./src -d dist/app",
"dev": "nodemon --watch src --ext ts --exec \"npm run build && npm run start\"",
```

npm run dev is going to watch for file changes inside src/ folder and then is going to compile the files and then re-open electron app.